# error: expected declaration before '}' token

Tags: c++, declaration

I have an error in my problem which I can't understand the reason of this. Please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
  float repeatitive (float[15]);
   float sort (float[15]);
    int i,j,k;
  float num[15],temp;
   main() 
  {
   printf("enter your numbers:\n");
   for(i=0;i<15;i++)
   scanf("%f",&num[i]);
   repeatitive(num);
    sort(num);
     }
   float repeatitive (float[])
     {
     for(i=0;i<=14;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<15;j++)
    {if(num[i]==num[j])
     {num[j]=0;}}
        printf("here is unrepeated numbers:\n");
      for(i=0;i<15;i++)
       if(num[i]!=0)    
        printf("%f\n",num[i]);
            }
     float sort (float[])
        {
      for(i=0;i<14;i++)
         for(j=i+1;j<15;j++)
         if(num[i]>num[j])
          {temp=num[j];
           num[j]=num[i];
           num[i]=temp;
            }
        for(i=0;;i++)
           if(num[i]!=0)
            printf("%f\n",num[i]);}
              }
                    }
```

here is my error

> [Error] C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled9.cpp:37: error: expected declaration before '}' token

Comment: How about starting from formatting your code properly?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center.

Answer (score 1):

First, format your code properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
float repeatitive (float[15]);
float sort (float[15]);
int i,j,k;
float num[15],temp;
main()
{
    printf("enter your numbers:\n");
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        scanf("%f",&num[i]);
    repeatitive(num);
    sort(num);
}
float repeatitive (float[])
{
    for(i=0;i<=14;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<15;j++)
        {
            if(num[i]==num[j])
            {
                num[j]=0;
            }
        }
    printf("here is unrepeated numbers:\n");
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        if(num[i]!=0)
            printf("%f\n",num[i]);
}
float sort (float[])
{
    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<15;j++)
            if(num[i]>num[j])
            {
                temp=num[j];
                num[j]=num[i];
                num[i]=temp;
            }
    for(i=0;;i++)
        if(num[i]!=0)
            printf("%f\n",num[i]);
}
}
}
```

Then, you'll soon find the two extra `}` after definition of `sort()`.

Comment: What about the lack of return type for `main` and the unnamed, unused function parameters?

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes, they are also problems. This is just a beginning of debugging.